# With CSS, how to prevent a <button> from jumping between state...positions?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm working to build a button styling where when the user hovers over a button, the button moves up 2 pixels. I have that working with the following on hover:

```
`transform: translateY(-2px);`
```

The problem is, if you move your mouse right under the button, the button starts to move but and the button now bounces/jumps from normal to active causing button jumpies.

Any idea on how I can implement the button moving up 2 pixels on hover but without the jumpies when the mouse is near the edge of the button?

```css
.ui.button {
  outline: none;
  height: 48px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding-top: 12.5px;
  padding-bottom: 12.5px;
  color: #fff;
  background: green;
  border: 1.5px solid darkGreen;
  box-shadow: 0 2px rgba(6,164,105,.25);
  transition: transform .1s ease-in-out,box-shadow .1s ease-in-out,-webkit-transform .1s ease-in-out,-webkit-box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
}

.ui.primary.button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  background: green;
  border-color: darkGreen;
  box-shadow: 0 4px rgba(6,164,105,.25);
}
```

```html
<button class="ui medium primary button  button-icon-with-text " role="button" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Primary Button</button>
```

Comment: The issue is that once it starts moving, it moves away from the mouse, so then you aren't hovering over it anymore and it starts to move back, but then you are hovering over it and it moves up again. It's not going into an active state. Use CSS animations to get around this.

Comment: If you don't need the transform you could do `.ui.primary.button:hover { margin-top: -2px; }`.

Comment: You can also ditch the vendor prefixes (`-webkit`) since what you are using them for has been standard in all browsers for quite some time.

Comment: @wazz wut?? using margin-top will cause the exact same jitter as transform:translateY

Comment: @FacundoCorradini https://jsfiddle.net/wazz/ejp9746p/

Comment: @wazz I think you're not understanding the issue. The button jumps up and down if you happen to position the mouse on the bottom 2px, as the movements gets it in an infinite loop of in-and-out of :hover. Your fiddle only makes it so much more noticeable as there is no transition

Comment: i don't see any jumping up and down, just up on hover and down on 'out'. it's prob not what he wants anyway.

Comment: @wazz enter the button from the very bottom, and keep it in the lower 2px...

Comment: @FacundoCorradini i had a feeling...i checked in chrome and see what you're talking about. i'm using firefox and there's no issue.

Comment: @wazz increase the value of the transaltion, you will see it better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similarly to Temani Afif's anwser, I would use a pseudo-element that's 2px longer than the element, but switching the overflow from hidden to visible on hover.

```css
.ui.button {
  position:relative; overflow:hidden;
  outline: none;
  height: 48px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding-top: 12.5px;
  padding-bottom: 12.5px;
  color: #fff;
  background: green;
  border: 1.5px solid darkGreen;
  box-shadow: 0 2px rgba(6,164,105,.25);
  transition: transform .1s ease-in-out,box-shadow .1s ease-in-out,-webkit-transform .1s ease-in-out,-webkit-box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
}

.ui.primary.button::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:calc(100% + 3.5px); /* translate + bottom border height*/
}
.ui.primary.button:hover {
  overflow:visible;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  background: green;
  border-color: darkGreen;
  box-shadow: 0 4px rgba(6,164,105,.25);
}
```

```html
<button class="ui medium primary button  button-icon-with-text " role="button" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Primary Button</button>
```

Comment: i also find another way to avoid the complex calculation of the different values ;)

Answer (score 2):

An idea is to use a pseudo-element that will cover the space under button after the translation and you will avoid this effect. So it's like you simply increase the total height of your element instead of translating it.

```css
.ui.button {
  position:relative;
  outline: none;
  height: 48px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding-top: 12.5px;
  padding-bottom: 12.5px;
  color: #fff;
  background: green;
  border: 1.5px solid darkGreen;
  box-shadow: 0 2px rgba(6,164,105,.25);
  transition: transform .1s ease-in-out,box-shadow .1s ease-in-out,-webkit-transform .1s ease-in-out,-webkit-box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
}
.ui.button:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  height:0;
}
.ui.primary.button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  background: green;
  border-color: darkGreen;
  box-shadow: 0 4px rgba(6,164,105,.25);
}
.ui.primary.button:hover:after {
  content:"";
  height:2px;
  bottom:-3.5px; /* Don't forget the border !*/
}
```

```html
<button class="ui medium primary button  button-icon-with-text " role="button" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Primary Button</button>
```

Another idea is to use a container for the button on where you apply the hover. This will work with any value of transalation and you avoid doing calculation to find the values of the pseudo-element:

```css
.ui.button {
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
  height: 48px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding-top: 12.5px;
  padding-bottom: 12.5px;
  color: #fff;
  background: green;
  border: 1.5px solid darkGreen;
  box-shadow: 0 2px rgba(6, 164, 105, .25);
  transition: transform .1s ease-in-out, box-shadow .1s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .1s ease-in-out, -webkit-box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
}

.contain {
  display: inline-block;
}

.contain:hover .ui.primary.button {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  background: green;
  border-color: darkGreen;
  box-shadow: 0 4px rgba(6, 164, 105, .25);
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
<button class="ui medium primary button  button-icon-with-text " role="button" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Primary Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm I was writing a similar answer, although positioning the pseudo-element in a different way.. Could you explain where the height 4px bottom -4px comes from? I'm not really following

Comment: @FacundoCorradini well we can simply make it 2px :) i was testing not sure why i kept it

Comment: oh that makes more sense. Thought I was missing something obvious lol

Comment: @FacundoCorradini well with 2px we also have a very small jump sometimes, so 1px more is fine :)

Comment: @FacundoCorradini oh i see it's the border :) that's why i made it more than 2px ;) .. so height sould be 2px and bottom -3px to consider the border